# how to save object into SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, google-maps, sharedpreferences

I need to save a map application entity object into `ArrayList<Marker>` in `SharedPreferences`. How do i do that?
Since now i am successfully saving LatLng values in `double` but now i found out i need to save the whole object.
This is my `OnPause()` so far:

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    key = 0;
    for (LatLng latlng : markerList) {
        double lat = latlng.latitude;
        double lng = latlng.longitude;
        editor.putString("key" + key, lat + "," + lng);
        key++;
    }
    editor.putInt("id", key);
    editor.apply();

    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: You can try to save it's json representation, and re-create it from that when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i do that?

You don't. `SharedPreferences` do not hold arbitrary objects. You are welcome to convert that `ArrayList<Marker>` into something that a `SharedPreferences` can hold (e.g., a `String` containing JSON), but that is up to you.

Usually, the focus is on:

- Saving model data, and a `Marker` is not model data
- Saving in a better container than `SharedPreferences`, such as a SQLite database or even a plain JSON file

Answer (score 2):

You can save only basic data types (like int, long, float, boolean) and String using SharedPreferences. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

If you want, you can convert it into a textual representation using tools like JsonParser, and convert it back to your original Object after retrieval. Find a tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm).

For saving map application entities, a better datastore like SQLite is recommended.